# How does the chrome.alarm api work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wonder what would happen when a chrome extension that uses the chrome.alarm api to fire a notification would reach it's onAlarm event when the PC is switched off?

Suppose, at 9 pm, I set the alarm to fire the notification after a delay of 30 mins, (at 9:30 pm) , and I switch off my PC at 9:25pm and then turn it back on at 9:35. Will the notification pop-up instantly after turning on, or will it be dismissed without popping up at all?

Please help.

Comment: Going completely off my experiences with the user interface (not the code): all notifications that were still pending will show, at least it does for me on YouTube!

Comment: Ummmm...thanks for that!

Comment: My guess is the event will fire but I've not come across anything that gives a clue. Try it and let us know.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235(v=vs.85).aspx), only CreateWaitableTimer can wake up a computer, but Chromium source code doesn't actually use it so, evidently, at least in Windows chrome.alarms won't wake up the PC.